# Ruby on Rails doesn't render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

jobs_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @job = Job.new(params[:job])
    render "preview" if @job.save
  end
```

preview.html.haml:

```
- render @job
```

_job.html.haml:

```
- content_for :title, "Job preview"
%h1= @job.title
```

The problem: @job in the _job.html.haml file does not get rendered, even though the title variable on the first line works fine.

Comment: are you certain `@job` has a value for `title`?

Comment: Your render is using `-`.  It should be `=` to echo the output.  Your `preview.html.haml` is incorrect, you can't 'render' and instance variable like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following in `preview.html.haml`

```
= render :partial => 'job', :locals => { :job => @job }
```

Then your partial will have

```
- content_for :title, "Job preview"
%h1= job.title
```

Shorter way of doing the above is

```
= render 'job', :job => @job
```

Comment: = render @job #should also work in case of using local variable `job` in the partial.